# Training & validation loss is NaN & accuracy is not increasing while training using Image Generator

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nan, loss

I'm using pretrained weights of VGG16 and fine tuning over another set of images. This is the code for it:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(vgg16)
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

These are where the data files are:

```
disease_false = pd.DataFrame({'file_path':[f for f in os.listdir(healthy_files)]})
disease_false['class'] = 0
disease_true = pd.DataFrame({'file_path':[f for f in os.listdir(disease_files)]})
disease_true['class'] = 1
images = pd.concat([
    disease_false,
    disease_true
])
images['class'] = images['class'].astype('float16')
```

This is how I've created the generator for validation & train dataset:

```
generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
train_image_generator = generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_images,
    directory=None,
    class_mode='raw',
    x_col='file_path',
    y_col='class',
    weight_col=None,
    target_size=IMG_DIM,
    color_mode='rgb',
    classes=None,
    batch_size=128,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123
)
val_image_generator = generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    val_images,
    directory=None,
    class_mode='raw',
    x_col='file_path',
    y_col='class',
    weight_col=None,
    target_size=IMG_DIM,
    color_mode='rgb',
    classes=None,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123
)
```

I've added an early stopping clause:

```
earlystopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = "val_loss", 
                                        mode ="min", patience = 10, 
                                        restore_best_weights = True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

This is the training code:

```
history = model.fit(train_image_generator, validation_data=val_image_generator, 
                    epochs=200,
                    callbacks =[earlystopping],
                    shuffle=True,
                    verbose=1)
```

But this happens while training:
[image]

Also, after the 10th epoch, the script throws an error for trying to save the best weights.
I tried changing the batch size and learning rate but it didn't work and my loss is still nan.

Comment: Did you freeze the pretrained model?

Comment: @MushfiratMohaimin yes i did.
for layer in vgg16.layers:
    layer.trainable = False